# Log4J Properties not found / no effect

Tags: java, log4j2

I've got a Web application with Tomcat and would like to add Log4J2. Logging to the console by default works just fine. Although, I've added a `log4j2.properties` to add a File appender to my project and write the log to a dedicated location. Unfortunately, it seems that my properties-File has no effect.

Path to properties-File: `/WEB-INF/log4j2.properties`

[image]

Configs of log4j2.properties

```
name=Log4j2PropertiesConfig
appenders=file
appender.file.type=File
appender.file.name=FileLogger
appender.file.filename=logs/app.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
rootLogger.level=all
rootLogger.appenderRefs=file
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref=FileLogger
```

How I create the logger inside a class:

```
private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try to put the file log4j2.properties into `src/main/resources`. It should allocate in classpath

Comment: According to the official documentation, it should be fine in the WEB-INF https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html, it needs to be there so it can be changed if necessary(exploded war-file etc)

Comment: see point 3 in your link : The "normal" search sequence using the classpath and file URLs will be used to locate the configuration file.

Comment: hm ok - what would I need to change in order to keep it in the WEB-INF?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-initialize-log4j-for-java-web-application

The tutorial solves my problem as it defines a way on how to keep the properties in the WEB-INF.